# Cannot find Data Generation Plan in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, testing

I have created SQL Server database by Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate means in Visual Studio project. I would like to fill it by test data automatically. Msdn says I should create a new item of Data Generation Plan. But I cannot find Data Generation Plan in new item menu... What did I miss? ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833267.aspx ?

Sorry, can't post comments yet......

Comment: Instead of run sql scripts provided by your link I used my already created database. And then followed this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833237(v=vs.80).aspx
And it did not work..

Comment: It is difficult to tell what may be happening. Here is a step by step tutorial that may help. http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1159-visual-studio-data-generation-plan.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately the question is still in place.. In your example they create an SQL Server project and there is Data Generation Plan node in the solution explorer yet. So my situation is slighly different. I have simple visual studio project with sql database created and connected. And I cannot see Data generation node and menu item..

Comment: If you follow the link I last posted above, and add the database project to your solution, then you are all set, and you have what you need. I do not understand why you feel you cannot add the project to your solution as outlined.

Comment: Dude because I have a lot of useful stuff in my existing solution and I do not want yo recreate it as Sql server project ) Also I am sure there should be a way to create Data Generator without choosing SQL server solution type at startup.

Comment: This approach is not to create a new solution - it is adding a project within your existing solution. You can add it in, do the populating of data, and then delete it again, leaving your existing solution intact.