# Cannot find Data Generation Plan in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: database, visual-studio-2015

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963778/cannot-find-data-generation-plan-in-visual-studio) related to VS 2010. However, I use VS 2015 and there is no Data Generation Plan at all. Are developers excluded this node at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this appears to be the [case](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2013/06/24/announcing-sql-server-data-tools-june-2013.aspx)

> With SSDT June 2013, Data Comparison was added along with several key
>   extensibility scenarios. However, Data Generation is not included and
>   is not planned to be released in the future. Third party tooling will
>   have to be relied upon for that functionality.

Comment: Are there any alternatives external tools for free use?